# php redirect not working but... working...?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, redirect

So I changed the structure of my site around some and such and I guess I broke the script some how.
When the user fills out a form correctly, they should be directed to the appropriate page. Instead it just sits there. However, if I test the form directly from form.php it works.

Here is some info on the form.

form.php is the actual form. submit.php does error checking, inserting into database, email message, redirect. script.js does ajax to make the form more user friendly.

Remember, this all works if I go directly to form.php and fill out the form. However, going to register.php which simply has added to it the header and footer and the body for form.php it does not work. What could be wrong?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Obligatory comment asking you to post your code if you want help.

Comment: I think it had to do with not realizing single line breaks would not be formatted as such. I edited that though. I'll try to see what code would serve best, since all the code works except when in the register.php page. So I guess I'll post that.

Comment: Well I was going through my code so I could try to paste it properly here and I ended up trying something. For some reason the jquery library from google apis was causing a conflict. I have no idea why but it works when I do not include that library. I swear it worked before though...

Comment: @Rich jQuery does not like double inclusion - problem might lie there.

Answer (score 0):

You propably included the jQuery framework twice, that causes much problems.